# oracle coherence segmentation fault

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-coherence

I just installed Oracle Coherence 3.6 on RHEL 5.5.  When I execute cache-server.sh I get a lot of GC warnings about allocating large blocks and then it fails with a segmentation fault.  Suggestions?  Here is the stack:

```
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 1024000):
        May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 1024000):
        May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
./bin/cache-server.sh: line 24:  6142 Segmentation fault      $JAVAEXEC -server -showversion $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$COHERENCE_HOME/lib/coherence.jar" com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer $1
[root@localhost coherence_3.6]# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01         partition       2097144 0       -1
[root@localhost coherence_3.6]# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3631880     662792    2969088          0     142636     353244
-/+ buffers/cache:     166912    3464968
Swap:      2097144          0    2097144
[root@localhost coherence_3.6]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      147G  6.7G  133G   5% /
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/hdb              2.8G  2.8G     0 100% /media/RHEL_5.5 Source
/dev/hda               57M   57M     0 100% /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.16_86992
[root@localhost coherence_3.6]#
```

Comment: how about a stack trace of the process crashing?

Comment: I only included the last few lines of the warnings which includes the 'Segmentation Fault' error.  The lines above that were just about 100 repeats of of the GC Warning.  Towards the end it would also say "GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this issue before, but to start, I'd suggest the following:

- Check for Linux updates. The JVMs for example now try to use large pages, and there have been some bugs in RH related to large pages that are fixed in the latest versions.
- Download the latest Java 7 JDK. While no JDK is entirely bug-free, we have done extensive testing with JDK 7 patch levels 15, 21 and 40.
- Download the latest version of Coherence. Coherence 12.1.2 is now out, but if you don't want to go for the very latest, then Coherence 3.7.1 is the suggested version. (The release after 3.7.1 is called 12.1.2. That is to align with Oracle versioning.)

Answer (score 0):

I would check your space allocation on disk and memory/swap.  You are probably running out of space somewhere.

df -h

free

Answer (score 0):

You could also check your Java version - make sure that you are well patched.
Are you using Java 6 or Java 7?

There are Oracle forums for Coherence - you should try and ask the question there - thats where the real experts hang out.

Comment: jdk160_21 is the java_home

Comment: Thats an ancient version of Java! Have you tried with a more recent version of Java and a recent version of Coherence? I know that Coherence is quite sensitive to NIO issues